# high chart column chart dynamic update with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, highcharts

a Ajax was returning the value which will assign to highchart column , but as per my below code the charts are not defined . first i have tried to create a user define function and call that function within ajax that was not give proper update then i have put the optiion variable and calling from this even tho objects are not created

below is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>C2S Success %</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

  <body class="theme-light">
    <font color="WHITE">
      <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" style="background:RED">Testing Etopup Dashboard </marquee>
    </font>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var options = {
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'chart1',
          type: 'column',
          height: 500,
          width: 530
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Success %'
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['Today', 'YesterDay', 'D-7'],
          title: {
            text: 'DAYs'
          }
        },

        plotOptions: {
          column: {
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true
            }
          }
        },
        series: []
      };
      $(function ready() {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'successper.php',
          type: 'GET',
          async: true,
          dataType: "json",

          success: function(point1) {
            options.series = point1;
            alert(point1);
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);


            setTimeout(ready, 50000);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart1" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;  margin: center"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

below is the output of php file and it will update on every 5 minute

```
 [
   {
     name: 'DEL',
     data: [96.65,96.71,96.37]
   },
   {
      name : 'MUM',
      data: [96.22,96.29,96.61]
   },
   {
      name: 'KOL',
      data: [97.21,97.56,97.24]
   },
   {
      name: 'CHN',
      data: [96.52,96.50,96.67]
  }
 ]
```

Comment: try to use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-setdata/) ie `chart.series[0].setData(point1);`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have some errors in your code.

1. You have the `<body>` tag inside the `<head>` tag.
2. The `$.ajax()` is expecting a `json` response, however your json data is incorrect.

**Valid json data:**

```
[
    {
        "name": "DEL",
        "data": [96.65,96.71,96.37]
    },
    {
        "name" : "MUM",
        "data": [96.22,96.29,96.61]
    },
    {
        "name": "KOL",
        "data": [97.21,97.56,97.24]
    },
    {
        "name": "CHN",
        "data": [96.52,96.50,96.67]
    }
]
```

Now, about the problem:

I'd suggest to follow this:

1. Make a helper request function that returns the `$.ajax()` function.

Example:

```
function request() {
      return $.ajax({
        url: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/0a573e0a882180d20df56357ac05345d/raw/541a5d3e17e686820c0476a630d490ff46fb47c2/successper.json",
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        dataType: "json"
      });
}
```

2. Call the request function in the `$(function(){});` block. By using `.done()` in the request function, you can get the json data from the URL. In the `done()` function build the HighChart content.

Example:

```
$(function() {
          request().done(function(point) {
            options.series = point;
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
          });
});
```

3. Set the `load` function in the `event` object in the chart options. Then with the current json data response you can use the `update()` series method.

[Series.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.update)

> **update (Object options, [Boolean redraw])** Update the series with a new set of options. For a clean and precise handling of new options,
>   all methods and elements from the series are removed, and it is
>   initiated from scratch. Therefore, this method is more performance
>   expensive than some other utility methods like setData or setVisible.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - options: Boolean New options that will be merged into the series' existing options.
> - redraw: Boolean Defaults to true. Whether to redraw the chart after the series is altered. If doing more operations on the chart, it is a
>     good idea to set redraw to false and call chart.redraw() after.

Example:

```
events: {
  load: function() {
    var series = this.series[0]; // Get the current series.
    setInterval(function() { // For every 5 seconds call the request function.
      request().done(function(point) {
        series.update(point); // Get the point (json data from the URL) and use the update(point) method.
        console.log("Updated with this: ", point);
      });
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

Something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>C2S Success %</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="theme-light">
  <font color="WHITE">
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" style="background:RED">Testing Etopup Dashboard </marquee>
  </font>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // (1)
    function request() {
      return $.ajax({
        url: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/0a573e0a882180d20df56357ac05345d/raw/541a5d3e17e686820c0476a630d490ff46fb47c2/successper.json',
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        dataType: "json"
      });
    }
    var options = {
      chart: {
        renderTo: "chart1",
        type: "column",
        height: 500,
        width: 530,
        events: { // (3)
          load: function() {
            var series0 = this.series[0];
            var series1 = this.series[1];
            var series2 = this.series[2];
            setInterval(function() {
              request().done(function(point) {
                series0.update({
                  name: point[0].name,
                  data: point[0].data
                });
                series1.update({
                  name: point[1].name,
                  data: point[1].data
                });
                series2.update({
                  name: point[2].name,
                  data: point[2].data
                });
              });
            }, 5000);
          }
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: "Success %"
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ["Today", "YesterDay", "D-7"],
        title: {
          text: "DAYs"
        }
      },

      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
          }
        }
      },
      series: []
    };
    // (2)
    $(function() {
      request().done(function(point) {
        options.series = point;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
      });
    });
  </script>
  <div id="chart1" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Don't forget to change `https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/0a573e0a882180d20df56357ac05345d/raw/541a5d3e17e686820c0476a630d490ff46fb47c2/successper.json` by your `successper.php` page.

Update:

As you have an array with 4 elements, change:

```
events: {
  load: function() {
    var series = this.series[0]; // Get the current series.
    setInterval(function() { // For every 5 seconds call the request function.
      request().done(function(point) {
        series.update(point); // Get the point (json data from the URL) and use the update(point) method.
        console.log("Updated with this: ", point);
      });
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

to this:

```
events: {
  load: function() {
    var series0 = this.series[0];
    var series1 = this.series[1];
    var series2 = this.series[2];
    var series3 = this.series[3];
    setInterval(function() { // For every 5 seconds call the request function.
      request().done(function(point) {
        series0.update({
           name: point[0].name,
           data: point[0].data
        });
        series1.update({
           name: point[1].name,
           data: point[1].data
        });
        series2.update({
           name: point[2].name,
           data: point[2].data
        });
        series3.update({
           name: point[3].name,
           data: point[3].data
        });
      });
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

**Update**: The php code of the successper.php page from my demo site.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");

$min = 0;
$max = 100;

$array = array(array(name => "DEL", data => array(mt_rand ($min*10, $max*10) / 10, mt_rand ($min*10, $max*10) / 10, mt_rand ($min*10, $max*10) / 10)),
        array(name => "MUM", data => array(mt_rand ($min*10, $max*10) / 10, mt_rand ($min*10, $max*10) / 10, mt_rand ($min*10, $max*10) / 10)),
        array(name => "KOL", data => array(mt_rand ($min*10, $max*10) / 10, mt_rand ($min*10, $max*10) / 10, mt_rand ($min*10, $max*10) / 10)),
        array(name => "CHN", data => array(mt_rand ($min*10, $max*10) / 10, mt_rand ($min*10, $max*10) / 10, mt_rand ($min*10, $max*10) / 10)));
echo json_encode($array);
flush();
?>
```

You can see the working example [here](http://dfjb.webcindario.com/dashboard.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: HI the chart is ploated now with data but it not updated in next cycle .

Comment: Make sure you have different data every 5 seconds because every 5 seconds the request event is triggered to the successper page.

Comment: @sunil4ur_s1 I've updated my answer. Let me know if this works well.

Comment: Just to add: don't try create json on your own, instead create am array and use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for it.

Comment: @DainisAbols I already did that. I've updated my answer so you can see.